# TypeError: do_before() missing 1 required positional argument: 'resp'

Tags: python, falconframework

I'm trying to attach a hook to a route. Although I'm following the code in documentation, something is wrong and hook returns error no matter what I do inside it.

components/counter.py:

```
def auth_request(req, resp, resource, params):
    pass


@falcon.before(auth_request)
class Counter(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        pass
```

app.py:

```
import falcon
from components import counter

api = application = falcon.API()

api.add_route('/counter', counter.Counter)
```

When I run this using `gunicorn` and request `localhost:8000/counter`, it returns:

`TypeError: do_before() missing 1 required positional argument: 'resp'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is

> api.add_route('/counter', counter.Counter`()` )

You need to pass an instance, not reference to the object.

Comment: Wow, haven't been working on it for some time, but just fetched the old code and it works! Thank you.